# APK Signature error

Tags: android, apk

I have an unsigned apk app and after signing it with a test keystore file I get an error when I launch the app.

These are the commands I used to sign the apk:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -alias 123456 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

jarsigner -verbose -keystore myapp.keystore -storepass none123 -keypass 123456 myapp.apk 123456
```

When launching it (Kindle Fire HDX) the app says I must redownload it from the store. Is there a convention for amazon kindle apps that I need to use?

Comment: do you have a store live version?

Comment: Yes but that's irrelevant. I need to install the apk that's not in the store.

Comment: did you try to change the app version to be different than the one on the store? are you signning the app with the same keystore that exists on the store?

Comment: Yes, the app version is not the same as in the store. Neither is they keystore which is why I'd like to find out how to sign the apk correctly in order for me to use the app.

Comment: I am just thinking with you. and since there is no responses from other!! why don't you try to set same version number and maybe same key store.

Comment: I don't have the keystore of the original app.

Comment: try using same version name and number

Comment: Sorry, internet cut out. Where would I get the version name/number?

Comment: from the Kindle store developer panel. and edit those in the manifest

Comment: Could you explain? Sorry, I'm having difficulty finding the right place in the developer panel.

Comment: is it kandle's developer console or google developer console? if kandle's I dont know any thing about it.

Comment: Which console do you mean? :o I just downloaded the apk online and rebuilt it. Now I need to sign it to install but it won't let me with the keystore that I'm using : /